# Problems with html and css design

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, tags, dimensions

I got a problem with making a menu.

I can't figure out how to make it a drop down menu although I've basically tried everything under the sun!

This is a company project and I need to get a drop down menu going!

So to give you an example - here's the link to the website I am working on right now -
http://smartliving.comule.com/brands.html. Please exclude the "css" or "cssmenu" tags in the previous tags!

The HTML code is as follows - the navigation bar is here: .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Smart-Living Bangladesh (BD)</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="abs.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demos/css/search.css" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demos/css/elastislide.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demos/css/elastislide1.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demos/css/custom.css" />



    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="demos/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="demos/images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <!-- Syntax highlighting -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demos/prettify/prettify.css" media="screen">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

    // Add the value of "Search..." to the input field
    $("#search").val("Search...");

    // When you click on #search
    $("#search").focus(function(){

        // If the value is equal to "Search..."
        if($(this).val() == "Search...") {
            // remove all the text
            $(this).val("");    
        }

    });

    // When the focus on #search is lost
    $("#search").blur(function(){

        // If the input field is empty
        if($(this).val() == "") {
            // Add the text "Search..."
            $(this).val("Search...");   
        }

    });

    $("#search-submit").hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("hover");
    });

});
</script>
    <script src="demos/prettify/prettify.js"></script>
    <script src="demos/js/modernizr.custom.17475.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery (required) & jQuery UI (for this demo only) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/tiny/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Anything Slider optional plugins -->
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.2.js"></script>

    <!-- Anything Slider -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/anythingslider.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.anythingslider.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#slider1').anythingSlider({
//          theme : 'metallic',
            expand       : true,
            autoPlay     : true

        });

        $('#slider2').anythingSlider({
            expand       : true,
            autoPlay     : true,    
            showMultiple : 2,
            changeBy     : 2
        });

    });
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-metallic.css" media="screen">

    <!-- AnythingSlider optional FX extension -->
    <script src="js/jquery.anythingslider.fx.js"></script>

    <!-- Index page only -->
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="jquery.vticker-min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#news-container').vTicker({ 
            speed: 500,
            pause: 3000,
            animation: 'fade',
            mousePause: false,
            showItems: 3
        });
            $('#news-container1').vTicker({
            speed: 700,
            pause: 4000,
            animation: 'fade',
            mousePause: false,
            showItems: 1
        });
    });
    $(function() {
            var initab = 0;
            var initab2 = 0;
        var lhash = window.location.hash;
        if (lhash) { 
            lhash.match(/^#(\d+)-(\d+)/);
            initab = RegExp.$1 - 1;
            initab2 = RegExp.$2 - 1;
        }

            $("ul.tabs").tabs("> .pane",{initialIndex:initab});
            $("ul.tabs2").tabs("> .pane2",{initialIndex:initab2});    
            $('ul li a').click(function () {location.hash = $(this).attr('href');});

    });
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demos/css/pages.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demos/colorbox/colorbox.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
            var initab = 0;
            var initab2 = 0;
        var lhash = window.location.hash;
        if (lhash) { 
            lhash.match(/^#(\d+)-(\d+)/);
            initab = RegExp.$1 - 1;
            initab2 = RegExp.$2 - 1;
        }

            $("ul.tabs").tabs("> .pane",{initialIndex:initab});
            $("ul.tabs2").tabs("> .pane2",{initialIndex:initab2});    
            $('ul li a').click(function () {location.hash = $(this).attr('href');});

    });
    </script>
    <script src="demos/js/demo.js"></script>
    <script src="demos/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <meta name="description" content="" />

    <meta name="keywords" content="" />

    <meta name="author" content="" />

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> 

    <meta name="keywords" content="carousel, jquery, responsive, fluid, elastic, resize, thumbnail, slider" />

    <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> 

    <meta name="keywords" content="carousel, jquery, responsive, fluid, elastic, resize, thumbnail, slider" />

    <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">    

<title>SMART LIVING BANGLADESH (BD)</title>
<style type="text/css">

img.adjusted {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .Invitation {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
  }
img.adjusted1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .Invitation1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 236px;
    height: 60px;
  }
img.adjusted2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .Invitation2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
  }
img.adjusted3 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .Invitation3 {
    position: relative;
    width: 718px;
    height:172px;
  }


img.adjusted4 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .Invitation4 {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    height:40px;
  }

</style>
            <form action="" id="search-form">
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />
                    <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>

</head>


<body>


<div id ="wrapper">

<div id="header">
    <img src="biggest1.png" alt="logo" />

</div> <!-- end #header -->

<div id="nav">
<div class="Invitation4">

  <img src="banner.jpg" class="adjusted1">
    <a class="issue" href="home.html">Home</a>
    <a class="issue" href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
    <a class="issue" href="FAQ.html">FAQ</a>
    <a class="issue" href="newproducts.html">New Products</a>
    <a class="issue" href="brands.html">Brands</a>
    <a class="issue" href="gallery1.htm">Gallery</a>
    <a class="issue" href="shoppingcart.html">Shopping Cart</a>
    <a class="issue" href="news.html">News</a>

    <a class="issue" href="wishlist.html">Wish List</a>
    <a class="issue" href="contact.html">Contact</a>

</div> <!-- end #nav -->
</div>
<div id = "featured">



<div id="footer">
<div class="Invitation2">

  <img src="banner1.jpg" class="adjusted2">




<ul>
                                <p style="text-align:center"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/groups/woodybd/" title="Facebook"><img class="display" src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>
                                <a href="http://bd.linkedin.com/pub/woody-bd/40/315/668" title="LinkedIn"><img src="images/google.png" alt="Google +" /></a>
                                <a href="http://twitter.com/#!/Woody_bd" title="Twitter"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a>
                                <a href="http://youtube.com/#!/Woody_bd" title="Tumblr"><img src="images/youtube.png" alt="Youtube"/></a>   
                                <a href="http://bd.linkedin.com/pub/woody-bd/40/315/668" title="LinkedIn"><img src="images/feed.png" alt="RSS Feed" /></a>
                                <a href="http://bd.linkedin.com/pub/woody-bd/40/315/668" title="LinkedIn"><img src="images/linkedin.png" alt="Linkedin" /></a>
                                <a href="http://bd.linkedin.com/pub/woody-bd/40/315/668" title="LinkedIn"><img src="images/wikipedia.png" alt="Wikipedia" /></a>
                                <p style="text-align:center"><b> <font size="0.1">© 2014 - Smart Living BD</font></b>                                   

    </ul>
</div>

</div> <!-- end #footer -->
             </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here's the PHP code for the page above - http://smartliving.comule.com/demos/css/pages.css
I have reproduced the code below. Please tell me how I can fix up the #nav tags and make a drop down menu for different brand names be displayed. I have tried with other codes and mixed it with different kinds of codes and ended up with mixed results.

```
body {
font-family: georgia,sans-serif;
font: normal 85%/1.1 "Lato", sans-serif;
color: white;
text-align: center

color:#333;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#wrapper {
width:960px;
/*background-color:#f1f1f1;*/
margin:0 auto;

}

#header {
width:960px;
height:135px;
margin:0 auto;

}


#nav {
width:960px;
height: 40px;

}
#nav span,
#nav a {
display:inline;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#ffffff;
}

#nav a:hover {
background-color:#000000;
height:40px;
}


#featured {
width: 960px;
height: 301px;
margin: 0 auto;

}

#bodies {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #f1f1f1;


}
#leftcolumn {
width:720px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border:0;
float:left;


}
#rightcolumn {
width:240px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border:0;
float:right;
}
#leftcolumn1 {
width:720px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
float:left;

}
#rightcolumn1 {
width:240px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border:0;
float:right;

}

#leftsidebar {
width:200px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border:0;
float:left;
}

#leftsidebar a {
text-decoration:none;
}
#leftsidebar ul, li{
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
}
#leftsidebar li {
list-style:none;
}
#content {
width:560px;
position: relative;
float:center;
padding:10px;
}

#rightsidebar {
width:200px;
float:right;
}

#rightsidebar a {
text-decoration:none;
}

#rightsidebar li {
list-style:none;
}
#news-container{
    width: 230px;
    float: right; 
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    border: 5px solid #333333;
}

#news-container ul li div
{
    border: 2px solid #aaaaaa;
    background: #ffffff;
}

#footer {
clear:both;
width:960px;
height:50px;

}

#footer p {
padding:5px;
}

/********************
  Overall Demo pages
 ********************/
body                   { font: 12px Georgia, Serif; background: #fff; color: #000; }
a, a img               { border: 0; text-decoration: none; }

#page-wrap, #demo2     { width: 100%; padding: 0 0px; margin: 0 auto 0px; position: relative; }

h1                     { font: bold 60px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; letter-spacing: -2px; margin: 10px 0; text-align: center; }
h2                     { font: bold 30px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; letter-spacing: -1px; margin: 0 0 10px 0; color: #000000; }
h2.title               { text-align: center; }
h3                     { font: bold 20px Georgia, Serif; margin: 0 0 10px 0; color: #003388; }
h5, .header            { font: bold 15px Georgia, Serif; text-align: center; }
pre, code              { font: 10px/1.8 Monaco, MonoSpace; margin: 0 0 15px 0; padding: 5px; background: #f5f5f5; block: inline; width: 100%; overflow-x: auto; }
blockquote             { margin-left: 30px; }

ul                     { margin: 0; padding-left: 35px; }
ul li                  { font: 15px Georgia, Serif; margin: 0 0 8px 0; }

#nav                   { 
display: block; 
width: 100%; 
margin: 0px auto; 
text-align: center; 
line-height: 3em; 
}
#nav a                 { 
text-align: center; 
background: black; 
color: white; 
border-radius: 5px; 
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
padding: 12px; 
white-space: nowrap; 
}
#nav a.issue           { 
background: #FF8C00; 
}
#nav a:hover, 
#nav a.current { 
background: #000; }
#nav .has-sub {
    z-index: 1;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#nav > ul {
  float: left;
}
#nav > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#nav > ul > li > a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#nav > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #FF8C00;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#nav > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#nav > ul > li.active:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #FF8C00;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#nav > ul > li.active > a {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF8C00 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ececec), color-stop(100%, #FF8C00 ef));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF8C00 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FF8C00 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FF8C00 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #FF8C00 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  background: #FF8C00;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF8C00 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ececec), color-stop(100%, #FF8C00 ef));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF8C00 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FF8C00 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FF8C00 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #FF8C00 0%, #FF8800 ef 100%);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#nav .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}
#nav .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#nav .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
#nav .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#nav .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #FF8C00;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ffa333;
  filter: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#nav .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #cc7000;
}
#nav .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #cc7000;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ffa333;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #cc7000;
}




#nav .has-sub:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav .has-sub ul {
    display:none;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
#nav .has-sub ul li{
    *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#nav .has-sub ul li a {

    backgroun: #ff8c00;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ffa333;
    filter: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#nav .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #cc7000;
}
#nav .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#nav .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#nav .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #cc7000;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ffa333;
}
#nav .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #b36200;
}   
.themeselector, .ani   { margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; }

#status                { color: #00a; font-weight: bold; }
.alert                 { color: #f00; font-weight: bold; }
.alert a, .attention   { color: #a00; }
.data                  { width: 100%; border: #555 0.5px solid; border-collapse: collapse; }
.data td, .data th     { border: #555 0.5px solid; padding: 0 5px; }
.data th               { background: #eee; }
.data .col             { width: 200px; }

/*****************
  Main demo page
 *****************/
#main #slider1         { width: 800px; height: 390px; list-style: none; }
#main #slider1 .panel5 ul { width: 200px; margin: 0 5px; }


/* For Specific Slides, these also apply to FX demo pages */
.textSlide             { padding: 10px 10px; }
.textSlide h3          { font: 20px Georgia, Serif; }
.textSlide h4          { text-transform: uppercase; font: 15px Georgia, Serif; margin: 10px 0; }
.textSlide ul          { list-style: disc; margin: 0; padding-left: 20px; }
.textSlide ul li       { display: list-item; }
.rightside             { float: right; margin: 0 0 2px 10px; }

.quoteSlide            { padding: 20px; }
.quoteSlide blockquote { font: italic 24px/1.5 Georgia, Serif; text-align: center; color: #444; margin: 0 0 10px 0; }
.quoteSlide p          { text-align: center; }

/***************************
  FX Demo Page
 ***************************/
/* Demo page accordions */
.accordion             { width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; }
.accordion .ui-widget-content a { color: #000000; }

/** Demo 1 **/
/* colorbox images to full size */
#demo2 #slider1        { width: 960px; height: 300px; list-style: none; }
.cboxPhoto             { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 !important; }
#cboxTitle             { color: #000 !important; }

/* Change metallic slider defaults to show thumbnails -
  using #demo2 (page wrapper) to increase this CSS priority */
#demo2 div.anythingControls { bottom: 15px; }
#demo2 div.anythingSlider-metallic .thumbNav a { background-image: url(); height: 10px; width: 30px; border: #000 1px solid; border-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius: 2px; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; }
#demo2 div.anythingSlider-metallic .thumbNav a span { visibility: visible; }

/* border around image to show current page */
#demo2 div.anythingSlider-metallic .thumbNav a:hover,
#demo2 div.anythingSlider-metallic .thumbNav a.cur { border-color: #fff; }
/* reposition the start/stop button */
#demo2 div.anythingSlider-metallic .start-stop { margin-top: 15px; }

/** Demo 2 **/
#demo2 #slider2        { width: 400px; height: 300px; list-style: none; }

/** Demo 3 **/
#demo2 #slider3        { width: 500px; height: 400px; list-style: none; }


/* position caption close button */
.caption-top .close,
.caption-right .close,
.caption-bottom .close,
.caption-left .close   { font-size: 80%; cursor: pointer; float: right; display: inline-block; }

/******************
  Expand demo page
 ******************/
#wrapper1              { width: 100%; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto; }
#wrapper2              { width: 50%; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto; }
#expand #slider1,
body#expand h2,        {margin-bottom:25px; }

/***************************
  Video Compatibility table
 ***************************/
.video-info            { width: 700px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 50px; font-size: 18px; }
.video-info h2         { text-align: center; }
.video-info ul,
.video-info li         { margin: 0; }
.video-info sup        { font-size: 12px; }
.video-info th.header  { width: 25px; }
.good, .bad, .prob     { color: #ddd; text-align: center; }
.good                  { background: #080; }
.bad                   { background: #800; }
.prob                  { background: #880; }
.group                 { border: #000 1px solid; }

/******************
  css3 demo page
 ******************/
.animations            { margin: 10px 10px 10px 5px; }
.ani                   { margin-top: 5px; }

/******************
  tooltips (Jatt)
 ******************/
.tooltip { cursor: pointer; }
#tooltip {
 min-width: 10px;
 color: #dddddd;
 background: #444;
 border: 1px solid #777;
 padding: 8px;
 display: none;
 opacity: 0.9;
 filter: alpha(opacity=90);
 text-align: left;
 border-radius: .5em;
 -moz-border-radius: .5em;
 -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
 z-index: 1000;
}
#tooltip .body {
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple if you know how to do it. What you need to do is have a `<ul>` then inside that `<ul>` another then in the styling what you need to do is when you hover over one of the `<li>` elements it displays the `<ul>` inside it.

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nvns3/

Code:

HTML:

```
<ul class='menu'>
    <li class='dropdown'><a>Hello 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Hello 1.1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Hello 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu, .menu ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
.menu li > a {
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu li > a:hover {
    background: blue;
     color: white;
}
.menu > li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.dropdown > a:hover + ul {
    display: block;
    left: -40px;
    top: 26px;
}
.dropdown ul:hover {
    display: block;
    left: -40px;
    top: 26px;
}
```

Comment: i did that...it gives me lots of problems... can u just write a sample  code and place it inbetween the clauses...i'll see if it works or not!